# How do I pass props value to inline css in react.js

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I want to pass props value to inline css.

Here is my code

```
function Thread(props) {
return(
    <div
    class="img"
    style={{ backgroundImage: "url(Assets/thread-1.webp)" }}
  ></div>
)}
```

I want to replace the value image url using `{props.ThreadImageUrl}` But I don't know how to write JS inside inline css.

Here is what I want to achieve.

```
function Thread(props) {
return(
    <div
    class="img"
    style={{ backgroundImage: {props.ThreadImageUrl} }}
  ></div>
)}
```

I tried JavaScript string Concatenation but it doesn't work. I'm still newbie to Js and React framework. Glad if someone can help me on this.

Comment: You can use string templates: ``style={{ backgroundImage: `url(${props.ThreadImageUrl})` }}``

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should do:

```
backgroundImage: `url(${props.ThreadImageUrl})`,
```